# Detect when a Fragment is loaded withing the same app launch

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am triggering an animation for the cards in my fragment on load. But whenever the user navigates to another fragment and comes back, this animation gets triggered again.

I want to be able to do the animation for only the first time within the app launch. I tried a few methods like the following but not able to achieve this.

1. Set a flag in onPause() of the fragment - doesn't seem to get triggered
2. Store a value in the Bundle onPause()

I would like to ask if playing animation each time a fragment loads is good UX as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a static boolean variable to your fragment. When the animation is shown once, set it to true. Check for its value the subsequent times and if it is true, do not run the animation. Something like this:

```
private class My Fragment extends Fragment {

private static boolean hasAnimationRun;

     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Some code

    if (!hasAnimationRun) {
    // Run your animation here.
       hasAnimationRun = true;
    }

    // Some code
    }
```

Comment: Is using static variable advised? I recently removed a static variable and replaced with a Shared Pref in another part of my project.

Comment: As long as you are not using static references to your views that can leak context, you are good to go. A static boolean is perfectly fine to use.

Comment: Accepting this answer, hoping there wont be a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to play animation only when app is launched first time on user's device, you are to use SharedPreferences. Use the @androholic solution, but boolean must not be static in this case. In onCreateView you must determine it every time, like this:

```
    ...
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    hasAnimationRun = preferences.getBoolean (FIRST_TIME_BOOLEAN_NAME, false);
    if (!hasAnimationRun) {
        //Run your animation here.
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(FIRST_TIME_BOOLEAN_NAME, true);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I want to run the animation whenever the app is launched, but not when moving between fragments.